# How to add hashmap into ArrayList in c++?

Tags: visual-c++, arraylist, c++-cli, hashmap

I want to add my hashmap into ArrayList in vc++ 08. My code is below.

```
    typedef std::tr1::unordered_map< std::wstring, std::wstring > hashmap;    
          hashmap numbers;
        ArrayList^ myAL = gcnew ArrayList;

myAL->Add(numbers); // gives error...
```

But it gives error that

```
error C2664: 'System::Collections::ArrayList::Add' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'hashmap' to 'System::Object ^'
1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

I tried for cast with object, but not succeeded. Can anyone help me **to add hashmap in arraylist**?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation you're trying above doesn't work because managed and native types don't interoperate directly in that way.

I suggest Kenny Kerr's classic C++/CLI article [Best Practices for Writing Efficient and Reliable Code with C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730837%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to figure out your specific interop scenario in more detail, but offhand I think what you want to do is embed a pointer to your native object in a managed object which you'll be able to add to your list structure.  If you use Mr. Kerr's [AutoPtr class](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2007/03/26/AutoPtr.aspx) (described in the article above and updated [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2007/03/26/AutoPtr.aspx)), you should be able to create a managed class containing the AutoPtr as a member, which you can add to your ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've changed my program. And add some alternate way .